# QGIS can't find osgeo after GDAL upgrade

Tags: qgis, gdal, mac

Mac OS 10.6.8: I installed QGIS 1.8.0 with GDAL 1.8; then another app requires GDAL 1.9 and installed it; now QGIS can't find osgeo [python-gdal]. (I can't find any trace of GDAL 1.8 left in my system.)

What needs to be edited to point QGIS to GDAL 1.9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install QGIS 1.8.0 from [KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis) and QGIS 1.9 from [Nightly Mac Build of QGIS from 'master' Branch](http://qgis.dakotacarto.com/), they need the same version of GDAL (the 1.9 version of Kynchaos, not the 1.8) and you need to understand some Principles of Mac OSX:

- GDAL is a **framework** ([What are Frameworks?](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WhatAreFrameworks.html)) installed in /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework.

And all the versions of GDAL are installed in this folder

[image]

The symbolic link **Current** points to the version used (the last one, 1.9 here) by QGIS (1.8 and 1.9) and the GRASS GIS version of Kyngchaos (6.4.2)  and the experimental builds of [Michael Barton](http://www.public.asu.edu/~cmbarton/files/grass_mac/OSX10.6-snowleopard/) (6.4.3, 6.5 and 7)

- osgeo is a Python module. Each version of GDAL in the Framework has its own version of osgeo (/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.9/Python/, /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.8/Python, etc.) but only the latest version is used.

The link with the modules of the standard Python (in /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/ for 10.6.8) is made by a .pth file

[image]

The content of this file is

> import sys; sys.path.insert(0,'/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/**1.9**/Python/2.6/site-packages')

That adds osgeo to the sys.path of the standard Python

[image]

If you really want use the 1.8 version, simply change the contents of this file to

> > import sys; sys.path.insert(0,'/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/**1.8**/Python/2.6/site-packages')

[image]

Comment: Of course I want to use 1.9, so edited the .pth file to say so. Thanks.